# webkit not animating border-radius on absolute positioned elements

Tags: css, animation, webkit

Trying to animate border-radius on a parent element acting as mask on child images. This works fine unless the image has `position:absolute`, which I need in this case. The problem in action (works fine in Firefox):

https://jsfiddle.net/dcm5kwvp/2/

**edit:code snippets**

```js
setTimeout(function() {
 document.querySelector('.mask').classList.add('loaded');
}, 100);
```

```css
.mask {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: border-radius .3s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.mask.loaded {
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
}

figure {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="mask">
<figure>
  <img srcset="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470434151738-dc5f4474c239?dpr=1&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb">
</figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Just to add more intrigue; if you resize the preview, you actually see the border-radius mask in action. Perhaps someone has an idea of how to trigger that reflow through CSS or JS

Comment: I'm in my cellphone, cannot provide an answer right now, but in my opinion this is a perfect example of what SVG is for. You should try to avoid animating properties such as width, height, border-radius, etc. that hits performance due to rendering. CSS animations should stick to opacity and transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution. This is a bug on Webkit engine with `position: absolute` disabling `overflow: hidden`.

The best way to solve it is to add a `-webkit-mask-image` on your element with a mask. In this case, it's a single pixel, and embeded as a base64 image.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
 document.querySelector('.mask').classList.add('loaded');
}, 100);
```

```css
.mask {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  transition: border-radius .3s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
  position: relative;
}

.mask.loaded {
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
}

figure {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mask">
<figure>
  <img srcset="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470434151738-dc5f4474c239?dpr=1&auto=format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb">
</figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that is such a strange bug, though. Thank you so much for the solution. Never would've come up with that myself.